How to extract url from a website using Python?
I'm working for a project for university and I would like to analyze the features of the most popular tv shows using web scraping and text mining.
So I tried to scrape the url from every tv show in the list in this site https://www.imdb.com/chart/toptv/ using the following code in Python, but in output I only receive the site url.
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.imdb.com/chart/toptv/m"
df = pd.DataFrame()
links = []
def extract_links(url):
    print("source url",url)
    global links
    source_url = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source_url.content,"html.parser")
    for link in soup.find_all('a',href=True):
        try:
            if len(links) >=100:
                return
            if link.get('href').startswith("https://") and link.get("href") not in links:
                links.append(link.get('href'))
                extract_links(link.get('href'))

        except Exception as e:
            print("Unhandled exception",e)

extract_links(url)
df = pd.DataFrame({"links":links})
df.to_csv("links.csv")

I also searched in the web and I found this code, but it doesn't work either.
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# send a GET request to the website
url = 'https://www.imdb.com/chart/toptv/'
response = requests.get(url)

# parse the HTML content of the page with BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

# find all links on the page
links = soup.find_all('a')

# print the href attribute of each link
for link in links:
    print(link.get('href'))

Can someone help me and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

you got a 403 forbidden, add headers to your requests headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'} (also check your url, is that trailing "/m" supposed to be there?)

As mentioned, the site checks your request headers and expects a user-agent, so try to provide the information to avoid the 403 error.
To select the links you are looking for directly by patterns, you could also use css selectors:
soup.select('a[href^="/title"]:has(h3)')

Example
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.imdb.com/chart/toptv/"

soup = BeautifulSoup(
    requests.get(url,headers={'user-agent':'some-agent'}).content,
    "html.parser"
)

pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {
            'link':f'https://www.imdb.com{link.get("href")}',
            'title': link.text.split('. ')[-1]
        }
        for link in soup.select('a[href^="/title"]:has(h3)')
    ]
)


Thank you, I tried and it worked, so the problem was that the server understood my request but refuses to authorize it because it was missing the  user agent?

So I tried proceed with my analyses extracting from each url sites, the reviews, title, ratings, ...., but in the output I receive "Failed to retrieve data from 'site url' . Status code: 403". I added the header as user agent but the problem still remains

Concerning your first comment, yes missing user-agent was the issue there. Concerning your second comment, this would be predestined for asking a new question with exact this focus and [mcve] specific to this case.
